# NeovimでG:にマウントしたGoogleドライブを開くことができない

Tags: vim, neovim

パソコン版Googleドライブを使ってG:にGoogleドライブをマウントした。

[パソコン版 Google ドライブを導入する](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7491144?hl=ja)

NVIM 0.4.4 での通りコマンドを実行しても開くことができない。

```
:e G:\
:e G:\マイドライブ\
```

ファイルを直接指定した場合、一つ目は開くが二つ目は開かないのか、バッファが切り替わらない。

```
:e G:\マイドライブ\a
:e G:\マイドライブ\b
```

vimでは問題なく開くことができる。

- 同様の事象が発生している方はいますか
- neovimでGoogleDriveを開ける方はいますか
- 解決策を教えてください

Comment: Vim でフォルダを開こうとするとファイル一覧が表示されるのは Netrw という標準プラグインが動作しているからです。Neovim にはこのプラグインが同梱されていないか、動作していないので Vim とは違う挙動になっていると思われます。

Comment: :e C:\でnetrwが起動します。